# WP Query to get posts with specific term_taxonomy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my wordpress installation, I have a custom taxonomy `event-categories` which is mapped to custom post type `event`.

In my single post display page, I need to list all posts which is posted in same `event-categories` of the current post. How can I write a wp query for this?

*Screen-shot for my custom taxonomy in custom post.*

[image]

Now tried like this `get_the_terms(the_ID(), 'event-categories')`.

So I got all `term_taxonomy_id`s related to the single post. Next how can I get all posts which have these `term_taxonomy_id`.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: when you say `list all posts which is posted in same event-categories of the current post`, do you mean all posts which have ALL the same categories as the current post or all posts which have ANY of the same categories as the current post? i will update my answer based on your response

Comment: @celeriko the second option, all posts which have ANY of the same categories as the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be about the most basic query to solve your problem.

```
$term_tax_ids = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'event-categories');
$terms = array();

foreach($term_tax_ids as $term_tax_id) {
  array_push($terms, $term_tax_id->term_id);
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $terms,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    )
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  echo '<div class="related_single">' . get_the_post_thumbnail();
  echo '<div class="related_title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></div></div>';
}
```

You should really read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), it has literally everything you could ever want to know about queries

Comment: The first line prints ``77`` on screen, and the remaining code displaying this error ``Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 815``

Comment: ah sorry thats because `get_the_terms` returns an array of objects and i assumed an array of strings, updated my answer

Comment: I think it's working fine, but am little confused. Can you help me to render these post with limit=5 in this html format.``<div class="related_single">
 <!-- post image here -->
 <div class="related_title">
 <!-- post title with post link -->
 </div>
</div>``

Comment: updated my code to demonstrate a simple display of the query, also note the `posts_per_page` argument to the query.

Comment: It's not entering to the last while loop. Note: I have one more post with all categories checked.

Comment: ok, i updated the answer to use the `get_` functions for string concatenation

Comment: No, it's not entering to the while loop, ``echo 'hi';`` does not work inside this while loop.

Comment: ok well as you can see from the print_r, the query is doing what you want but it isnt getting any results. are you sure that the taxonomy slug is correct? that you have posts in these categories in this taxonomy?

Comment: try `foreach($term_tax_ids as $term_tax_id) {
  array_push($terms, $term_tax_id->term_taxonomy_id);
}` instead, it looks like from the print_r that the converted SQL is looking for `term_taxonomy_id` and not `term_id`

Comment: No luck, I have seven posts with all categories checked.

Comment: and they are all `events` and not regular `posts`?

Comment: updated to use `event` instead of `event-categories`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine when I updated the ``post_type`` from ``post`` to ``event``

Comment: And why this line ``$term_tax_ids = &get_the_terms(the_ID(), 'event-categories');`` displays a count ``77`` on screen without echo or something.

Comment: why do you have an `&` in front of the function call?

Comment: it must be coming from somewhere prior to this in your code

Comment: I commented all and then uncommented this line, then it shows.let me try wordpress upgrade.

Comment: you are using `the_ID()` which will always display it. use `get_the_ID()` instead, i will update my answer

Comment: yes, it's working fine. And how to make it order by event date?

Comment: `event date`? as in the date the `event` post was created, or some custom field you have that stores the event's date?

Comment: It's custom field see ui here (date and time) http://postimg.org/image/5tr5wtuc7/bfa53b64/ . ``event_start_date``

Comment: not sure its entirely possible just through your query, it depends on the structure of your custom fields, i would HIGHLY suggest reading the Codex link i put in my answer, it will be a lot more effective than trying to pick my brain through the internet.